# Unable to perform RoutedEventHandler

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, routed-events

I have loop to create a column of button and now i wish to implemented the eventhandler into all the buttons but is not working.

The iteration to create a column of button

```
 For e As Integer = 0 To 19
                btnFriday(e) = New Button()
                btnFriday(e).Height = 23
                btnFriday(e).Width = 150
                btnFriday(e).SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 9)
                btnFriday(e).SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, e + 1)
                btnFriday(e).Click +=  New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf btnBookSlot_Click)
                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(btnFriday(e))
    Next
```

I wish to do like when 1 of the btnFriday is clicked then perform the below event which is open a childwindow called as Bookslot

```
Private Sub btnBookSlot_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim bookSlot As New BookSlot()
    bookSlot.show()

End Sub
```

And i receive error like

> Public Event Click(sender As Object, e As
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called
>   directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event

Most of the solutions were built using C# with silverlight and they seem to be working great. While i having problem by using VB.NET with silverlight Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all you need to change is:

```
 btnFriday(e).Click +=  New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf btnBookSlot_Click)
```

To:

```
  AddHandler btnFriday(e).Click, AddressOf btnBookSlot_Click
```